# Animated particle texture linked to particle age

Tags: texturing, particles

Is it possible to create a particle system emitting objects onto which there is a video clip as its texture, with the video clip starting from the beginning of the clip, on each particle when the particle is spawned.

Currently they are all in sync, regardless of when the particles were spawned.

I'm using 2.91.

Thanks.

Matt

Comment: Not without scripting or doing a whole lot of tedious work-- you need a separate image texture for every frame of the film.  Blender is not designed to load an entire video in a single frame, because the memory use would get out of control really, really fast.  It loads only the exact frames you tell it to load.

Comment: Soooo basically as the video plays (and the animation), the particles' textures change? I think if you give the initial emitting object an image (or for our purpose a video) texture on a generic principled BSDF shader, the particles color will correspond to the color of the part of the texture it was emitted from.